# MvvmCross Android ImageView binding image src

Tags: android, android-listview, data-binding, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

So here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a MainLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
....>
   <MvxListView
   local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_template"
   local:MvxBind="ItemsSource BitmapList"
   ..../>
</LinearLayout>
```

The ItemsSource 'BitmapList' is an ObservableCollection.
I'm converting views to bitmaps and storing inside of this. The list of bitmaps won't exceed about 20~30. Also, as you can tell, there isn't any adapter. I'm using mvvmcross binding.

The code for item_template.axml is:

```
<LinearLayout
....>
   <ImageView
   ....
   local:MvxBind="????"
   ..../>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, ???? is what I'm missing. 
Question 1: Can I bind a collection of bitmap directly to ImageView's path?
Question 2: If yes, how?
Question 3: If no, what do I do about it?

Alternate question: Is it a good idea to store a list of 20~30 bitmaps in a list at runtime? I'm assuming it'll stay in the internal memory.

Thanks a lot fellas!

Answer (score 0):

Try `local:MvxBind="Bitmap ."`

If you look in [MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/2da590505572743bdb1c60eea2dbeeb3ca094ed1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/MvxAndroidBindingBuilder.cs#L103), you'll see the pre-defined binding properties. ImageView has a binding for *Bitmap*. The period (.) means the current item. Since your ItemsSource is a collection of Bitmaps, this should work.